# Property value set by Observable loses value on routerLink redirect

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

The problem I encounter is: when going from 'localhost/' to 'localhost/accounts/:account_id' or vice versa, the property set by AngularFire Observable loses its value.

In my Chrome DevTools 
In the first call of *onInit()*,
**this.accounts** are logged

but every *2nd* call of *onInit()* 
 
**this.accounts** are not logged; and accounts.component.html looping through accounts show no value at all unless there are changes in Firestore or the whole page is refreshed.

What i'm trying to achieve is **this.accountsService.getAccounts()** be fired when onInit() is called

Here is my code so far 

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'accounts/:account_id', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

home.component.html

```
...
  <app-accounts></app-accounts>
...

<h2 class="">Transactions</h2>
<div class="list-group list-accounts">
<a routerLink="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
Add Funds
</a>
<a routerLink="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Spend</a>
<a routerLink="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Transfer</a>
<a routerLink="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Receive</a>
</div>
```

accounts.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountsService {
accountsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Account>;


accounts: Observable<Account[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.accountsCollection = this.afs.collection<Account>('accounts');
    this.accounts = this.accountsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Account;
        data.accountId = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });

  }


  getAccounts() {
    return this.accounts;
  }


}
```

accounts.component.ts

```
export class AccountsComponent implements OnInit {


accounts: Account[];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private accountsService: AccountsService) { }

ngOnInit() {

console.log('onInit()');

this.accountsService.getAccounts().subscribe( accounts => {
  this.accounts = accounts;
  console.log(this.accounts);
});

}

}
```

and

account.component.html

```
<div class="list-group list-accounts">
    <a *ngFor="let account of accounts"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    routerLink="/accounts/{{account.accountId}}"> {{account.name}} </a>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `<router-outlet>` and where did you provide `AccountsService`.?

Comment: @TomaszKula <router-outlet> is in app.component.html and AccountsService is in app/src/services/account.service.ts (code in description)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your value in a Subject or BehaviorSubject:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AccountsService {
accountsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Account>;


private accounts = new BehaviorSubject<Account[]>([]);

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.accountsCollection = this.afs.collection<Account>('accounts');
    this.accountsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
     this.accounts.next( 

        actions.map(a => {
           const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Account;
           data.accountId = a.payload.doc.id;

           return data;
        })

      );
    });

  }


  getAccounts(): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.accounts.asObservable();
  }


}
```